# android:imeOptions not go to the exact next EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, imeoptions

I have 2 EditText with id `(et_1 and et_2)` in a layout, and I set

for et_1

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext",
android:nextFocusForward="@+id/et_2"
```

when `et_1` gets focus and the the software keyboard shows "Next", and when I click "Next", the focus doesn't go to `et_2`, but to another EditText in another fragment layout. Why is it this way?

How to make the focus go to et_2?

Thanks.

Comment: It's weird because I found focus just went from et_1 to et_2 in another device, maybe there's something wrong about my device.

Comment: try adding "inputType" in et_1 and then check whether next working or not?

Comment: Thanks, I had set inputType.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing,

```
android:nextFocusForward="@+id/et_2"
```

to

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_2"
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in one of my apps. What I did instead was have a listener in my activity for when "Next" was pressed and then just manually changed the focus. Like this:

```
final EditText et_1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_1);
final EditText et_2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_2);

// listen on the et_1 EditText
et_1.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) { // "Next was selected"
            et_2.requestFocus(); // focus on et_2
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: @BruceDu Great. Please accept one of the answers by pressing the checkmark to the left of the question. It lets people know that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I realised referencing does not hide the keyboard

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_2"
```

To Hide the Keyboard add actionDone

```
     <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editTextEnterAmount"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Enter Amount"

                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"

/>
```